# Why object is not detecting by Physics2D Raycast in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collider

I make a 2d game in unity, and I need your help.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD71Z.png)
.

The game is that randomly create 9 colored dots as shown in the picture.
The player must connect the dots with the corresponding color. All this I did.

**Problem:**
As soon as I click on one dot and move immediately to another for connect, it does not connect immediately, but after about 1 second.
If I click on one point and hold about 1 second, and then quickly move to the next point, it connects.

That is, I need to either wait for the first point, or for the second.

As it turns out, all this is because of colliders and Raycast.
He does not have time for check.

Example of my code **(very shortened)**:

```
Vector3 startPos;
Vector3 endPos;

Vector3 mousePos;
Vector2 mousePos2D;
RaycastHit2D hit;

void Update() {

mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
mousePos2D = new Vector2 (mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
hit = Physics2D.Raycast (mousePos2D, Vector2.zero);

// Here comes the creation of the first point and the connection 
if (Input.GetMouseDown(0)) {
if (hit.collider != null) {
color = hit.collider.tag;
startPos = hit.collider.transform.position;
endPos = mousePos2D;
}
}

// Here comes the creation line between dots 
if (Input.GetMouse(0)) {
if (hit.collider != null) {
if (hit.collider.tag == color) {
endPos = hit.collider.transform.position;
// Here is instantiated new line and with startPos and endPos and I set
startPos = endPos;
endPos = mousePos2D;
}
}
}

// Here points are deleted if connected 
if (Input.GetMouseUp(0)) {
    // Nothing important
}
}
```

The problem is that: in "Input.GetMouseDown(0)", even if the mouse passes through the object "hit.collider is equal null", and after about 1 sec, hit.collider is not null and give the color tag.

Video example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8x6TSBfBIzc

All code script:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QKRInr26acu-E4zXPUf-DbW0h9zbsnUr

How to solve this problem with expectation? Why it does not connect immediately?

Comment: Physics operation are not recommended in the Update method (in particular at every frame without condition like in your code) but in the FixedUpdate method. It can (but is unlikely to) explain the delay.

Comment: Does not help ;(

Comment: I found from what is happening, 
In console update:
When I click on dot> to dot(0) is added 1, and if I keep button down, to dot(1) is added random (+7 ... +15), first click is explain the delay.

Comment: I found an error, it turns out I turned off in another script for 0.5 collider of the object, sorry